# python -We ResourceWarning not erroring

Tags: python, python-asyncio, warnings

If I take a simple test script like this, which results in ResourceWarning:

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp

async def main():
    client = aiohttp.ClientSession()
    await client.get("https://google.com")

asyncio.run(main())
```

Run it with `python -bb -We -X dev test.py`.

I'm expecting the `ResourceWarning` to error and result in a non-0 exit code.

Actual result:

```
Exception ignored in: <function ClientSession.__del__ at 0x7f397e04beb0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/s/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 342, in __del__
    _warnings.warn(
ResourceWarning: Unclosed client session <aiohttp.client.ClientSession object at 0x7f397dfce4b0>
Exception ignored in: <function BaseConnector.__del__ at 0x7f397e0b6eb0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/s/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 281, in __del__
    _warnings.warn(f"Unclosed connector {self!r}", ResourceWarning, **kwargs)
ResourceWarning: Unclosed connector <aiohttp.connector.TCPConnector object at 0x7f397dfce690>
Exception ignored in: <socket.socket fd=7, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=6, laddr=('192.168.1.18', 45750), raddr=('172.217.169.4', 443)>
ResourceWarning: unclosed <socket.socket fd=7, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=6, laddr=('192.168.1.18', 45750), raddr=('172.217.169.4', 443)>
Exception ignored in: <function _SelectorTransport.__del__ at 0x7f397e8264b0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 696, in __del__
    _warn(f"unclosed transport {self!r}", ResourceWarning, source=self)
ResourceWarning: unclosed transport <_SelectorSocketTransport fd=7>
Exception ignored in: <function _SelectorTransport.__del__ at 0x7f397e8264b0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 696, in __del__
    _warn(f"unclosed transport {self!r}", ResourceWarning, source=self)
ResourceWarning: unclosed transport <_SelectorSocketTransport fd=6>
Exception ignored in: <socket.socket fd=6, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=6, laddr=('192.168.1.18', 42986), raddr=('142.250.187.206', 443)>
ResourceWarning: unclosed <socket.socket fd=6, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=6, laddr=('192.168.1.18', 42986), raddr=('142.250.187.206', 443)>
```

0 exit code indicating success.

How do I ensure the program actually fails on a warning?

Comment: As a workaround I've currently got this to check if the word 'warning' is in the output:
`python -bb -We -X dev test.py 2>&1 | tee /dev/tty | ( ! fgrep -i 'warning' > /dev/null ) || exit 1; if [ ${PIPESTATUS[0]} -ne 0 ]; then exit 1; fi`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-We` makes the interpreter raise an exception instead of a warning. However, within the `__del__` function [no exception can be raised](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__). Instead, such exceptions are printed to the stderr and the execution continues. This behavior can be overridden via [`sys.unraisablehook`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.unraisablehook).

Here's a modified version of the code that will return non-zero exit code:

```python
import aiohttp
import asyncio
import os
import sys


def custom_hook(args):
    os._exit(7)


async def main():
    client = aiohttp.ClientSession()
    await client.get("https://google.com")


sys.unraisablehook = custom_hook
asyncio.run(main())
```

Notice that instead of `sys.exit()` I use `os._exit()`. That's because `sys.exit()` raises SystemExit exception which is a bad idea in our case.

Comment: Great. Is there any way to do this without modifying the code? I suppose I can just write a small script that imports `main()` and runs it in this test environment atleast.

Comment: Without modifying/writing any code -- I don't think so.
Without modifying existing code -- yes. You just have to create a wrapper outer module that will override `sys.unraisablehook`, import your module and run its `main()` function.

Comment: OK, condensed it to `python -bb -We -X dev -c "import asyncio, os, sys, ${f%.*}; sys.unraisablehook = lambda _: os._exit(1); asyncio.run(${f%.*}.main())"` where $f is the filename.

Comment: Seems to work locally, but for some reason all my warnings disappear on the actual test runs now...  https://github.com/aio-libs/aiocache/pull/610

Comment: Hmm, seems if I `del` the module at the end, it triggers the warnings again. But, then the hook doesn't run, so it still exits successfully. No idea what's happening anymore.

Comment: It is not guaranteed that `__del__()` methods are called for objects that still exist when the interpreter exits: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__

Comment: Right, that explains why `del` is helpful. But, still confused why the unraisablehook no longer works...